# Changes not being observed in a MutableLiveData List

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, kotlin

I have a MutableLiveData list in my repository as follows :

```
class AnswerRepository {
    private var _answerList = mutableListOf<Answer>()
    var answerList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Answer>>()

    fun addAnswerInList(answer: Answer) {
        _answerList.add(answer)
        answerList.value = _answerList
        Log.e("AnswerRepository", "Answer List size : ${answerList.value?.size}")
        Log.e("AnswerRepository", "_Answer List Size : ${_answerList.size}")
    }

    fun returnAnswerList(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Answer>> {
        return answerList
    }
}
```

An item is added in `'answerList`' (the MutableLiveData List) in a service as given below :

```
class FloatingWidgetService : Service(), View.OnClickListener{
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository()

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        //Getting the widget layout from xml using layout inflater
        mFloatingView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.floating_widget, null)


        initialiseViews()

        setListeners()
}

         @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

        when (p0?.id) {
            R.id.next -> {
                addItemInList()
            }
        }

    private fun addItemInList(){
           val answer = Answer(questionNumber, selectedOption, questionStatus)
                    answerRepository.addAnswerInList(answer)
}
```

Then this MutableLiveData List (`answersList`) is being observed in the fragment using viewmodel between repository and the fragment as follows :

ViewModel :

```
class SendAnswerToCloudViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository()

    val answerList  = answerRepository.returnAnswerList()
}
```

Fragment :

class SendAnswerToCloud : Fragment() {

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    val binding: FragmentSendDataToCloudBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
        inflater,
        R.layout.fragment_send_data_to_cloud,
        container,
        false
    )

    binding.lifecycleOwner = this

    viewModel.answerList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        Log.e("SendAnswerToCloud", "isChangeTrigerred")
        val answer = viewModel.answerList.value?.last()
        Log.e(
            "SendAnswerToCloud",
            "QuestionNumber : ${answer?.questionNumber}, SelectedOption : ${answer?.selectedOption}, QuestionStatus : ${answer?.questionStatus}"
        )
    })


    return binding.root
}
```

}

The list is successfully updated in the repository when `addAnswerInList`is called in the service. However nothing happens in the fragment (as the logs don't appear in the logcat).

So, what am I doing wrong ? Any kind of help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: this  `val answer = viewModel.answerList.value?.last()` could be `it.last()`, since the list is being passed to the observer object.

Comment: "An item is added in 'answerList' (the MutableLiveData List) in a service as given below" What service are you talking about? Maybe the issue is that you create a new instance of `AnswerRepository` which creates another `MutableLiveData` and posts updates there. If you can post more of the code where you have `fun addItemInList`.

Comment: Thanks @JeneaVranceanu for your comment. I updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your implementation is that you instantiate two `AnswerRepository` objects instead of one. Thus, **you get two** `var answerList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Answer>>()` instead of one. While your `SendAnswerToCloud` to cloud listening for changes on the first `answerList` your service edits the other `answerList`. That is the reason you do not see any changes.

Make sure you create only one `AnswerRepository` object.

In programming people use [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection#:~:text=In%20software%20engineering%2C%20dependency%20injection,object%20is%20called%20a%20service.) and optionally in combination with [singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). Sometimes you can get away using only singleton pattern, but this is a less flexible solution and not so easy to test.

### Detailed reponse

So the problem occurs because you have first object instantiation in `FloatingWidgetService` class:

```
class FloatingWidgetService : Service(), View.OnClickListener{
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository() 
    ...
```

and the second instantiation in `SendAnswerToCloudViewModel` class:

```
class SendAnswerToCloudViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository()
    ...
}
```

This way you create two absolutely separate objects. Each one of them occupies different address in memory, and all of the objects you create inside `AnswerRepository` are also different between these two instances.

Imagine placing those declarations one after the other like this:

```
class SendAnswerToCloudViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository()
    private val answerRepository_second = AnswerRepository() 
    ...
}
```

If you later compare them by `equals` method or by `==` operator you will get result `false` because they are two different objects. Thus, if you set a new value to `answerList` of `answerRepository` subscribers of `answerList` stored in `answerRepository_second` **will not receive any updates**.

### Solution

Add companion object and make the primary constructor private.

```
class AnswerRepository private constructor() {
    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AnswerRepository? = null

        fun getInstance(): AnswerRepository {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = AnswerRepository()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    }

    private var _answerList = mutableListOf<Answer>()
    var answerList = MutableLiveData<MutableList<Answer>>()

    fun addAnswerInList(answer: Answer) {
        _answerList.add(answer)
        answerList.value = _answerList
        Log.e("AnswerRepository", "Answer List size : ${answerList.value?.size}")
        Log.e("AnswerRepository", "_Answer List Size : ${_answerList.size}")
    }

    fun returnAnswerList(): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Answer>> {
        return answerList
    }
}
```

Now instead of writing declarations with constructor invocation:

```
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository()
```

You will call `getInstance()` method to get `AnswerRepository`.

```
    private val answerRepository = AnswerRepository.getInstance()
```

This pattern is called singleton. When you ensure that your program has only one instance of a specific class.

**Strongly recommend you to complete Essentials and Kotlin maps [here](https://hyperskill.org/knowledge-map/357?v=table).**

Comment: Thanks @JeneaVranceanu !! Actually I am new to android, and I don't understand where I am instantiating two `AnswerRepository` objects. It would be really, really helpful if you can point out where I am creating the two instances(and which one i should omit). Thanks again . 

Comment: @IqbalSingh, I've update the answer. Please, make sure you will get yourself familiar with most important stuff in programming. I personally completed Kotlin map and partially Essentials map in Jet Brains Academy: https://hyperskill.org/knowledge-map/357?v=table This resource is very helpful for anyone starting in programming and learning Kotlin. Though, they will require payment after January 1st 2021. Right now it is free so don't miss out.

Comment: Hi @JeneaVranceanu, A BIG thank you with a lot of love !  I am really grateful for your time and efforts. And it was so awesome of you to provide the resource. It is really helpful. Thanks again , and hope you have a good day . 